# Selecting multiple text spots with visual mode?

Tags: text, vim, markdown

I'm doing some markdown editing in vim on a file. I'm trying to convert it to markdown with code highlighting, etc.

```
- Arithmetic operators:`+,−,*, /`
- Constants: `e`, `pi`
- Functions: (abs x), (max x y... ), (ceiling x) (expt x y), (exp x),
    (cos x), ...
```

I want to select only the things that are in parantheses (including the parantheses) in the following using visual mode (so they would be disjoint by the commas):

`(abs x), (max x y... ), (ceiling x) (expt x y), (exp x),
    (cos x), ...`

And then do `` S` `` to surround the each piece of text with backticks. How can I do this without selcting each one, then doing `` S` `` repeatedly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I do this without selcting each one, then doing S` repeatedly?

This is actually what works best in Vim. With a bit of help from macros:

Interactive version:

```
/(.\{-})<CR>
qqysa)`nnq
@q
@@
@@
```

... till you do them all and wrap around to where you started.

Non-interactive "just do it" version:

```
:set nows<CR>
gg
/(.\{-})<CR>
qqqqqysa)`nn@qq@q
```

You'll probably want to go back to `:set ns` afterwards.

Of course, if you know that there are no nested parentheses, then the simplest answer is using `:s`, like the other answerer suggested.

EDIT with the explanation of the macro:

`qqqqq...@qq@q` is a loop. Here's how it works:

- `qq` followed by `q` clears the `q` register. This will be important later.
- `qq` starts the macro recording.
- `ysa)` surrounds around the parentheses with `` ` ``.
- `nn` goes to the next match. We have to do it twice, because surround jumps to before the paren, and `n` will match the same parentheses again.
- `@q` invokes the `q` macro. It is empty, so this does nothing... now. However, read further...
- `q` stops the macro recording, and stores it to the `q` register.
- Now that `q` is not empty any more, we can execute it with `@q`. However, during the execution `q` will *still* not be empty, so when we get to the point in the macro that did nothing during the recording, the macro will relaunch, giving us a primitive, but functioning, recursion loop.
- The loop stops when something in it breaks: for example, not being able to go to the next match. Usually, you'd just change all the matches so no more matches remain; however, the edit this macro does does not make the match fail, so we have to rely on `:set nows` to make sure we don't continue infinitely adding backticks to all parentheses.

After a bit of thought, you can actually rewrite the pattern so that `:set nows` (and additional `n`) is not needed:

```
/`\@<!(.\{-})<CR>
qqqqqysa)`n@qq@q
```

This matches a pair of parentheses not preceded by a backtick, so that after all matches have been dealt with there is no match for `n`, naturally breaking the loop.

If anyone thinks this is complex... note that most editors plain can't do it (since this takes into account proper parenthesis nesting, whereas I haven't yet seen an editor with search-replace robust enough to be able to pull it off).

Comment: I don't get ``qqqqqysa)`nn@qq@q``. I thought you couldn't put a macro in another macro? `qqq` just starts and quits recording the macro... Then `qq` records another, and also plays it back? Could you explain this in your answer?

Comment: You can't record a macro within another macro, but you can call one inside a macro definition. `qqq` just deletes whatever was in `"q` before. It shouldn't be necessary here.

Comment: @L3viathan It’s crucial that `@q` does nothing while recording; as `q` is my go-to macro register, I always clear it before a loop. herophant, I’m on mobile now, I’ll explain in more detail when I have a proper keyboard.

Comment: Although this may show the power of Vim, it will probably take a long time for a beginner like me to get there lol. When you posted this answer I didn't even know what macros were..thanks

Comment: Yeah. it's not simple to use loops like this off-the-cuff. Typically, if there's a small number of instances, I'll just do it manually, since the time invested to write the loop correctly would be larger than just doing it by hand. If there's a lot, then I'll experiment manually for a bit to find the right incantation to put in the loop before writing the loop itself. However, I am using `qqqqq...@qq@q` as a set phrase now, so I don't need to think about that bit, just the bit that does the work. (Obviously, I could also use `qaqqa...@aq@a`, but that doesn't flow off the fingers as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Using a global command (assuming `S`` comes from surround.vim):

```
:global/(/normal f(ysab`
```

(This affects the whole file, and may only do one change at a time. Repeat with `@:`)

With a macro:

```
qqf(ysab`q
```

Repeat with `@q` and then `@@`

Or with substitute:

```
:substitute/([^)]\+)/`&`/g
```